# Process completed with exit code 66 during setup of Github Actions iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, github, github-actions

I would like to setup a Ci for my iOS project however I keep getting

```
Set up job

Run actions/checkout@v1

Build

##[error]Process completed with exit code 66.
Run xcodebuild build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO

xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/runner/runners/2.164.0/work/TestProj/TestProj does not contain an Xcode project.

##[error]Process completed with exit code 66.

Complete job
```

On GitHub my project setup TestProj -> TestProj -> TestProj.xcodeproj. Im not sure how to setup the project path so that it works.

This is the swift.yaml file contents for the CI job:

```
name: Build and Test

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build
      run: xcodebuild build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps always run at the root of your repository, so if your project can't be found there you might need to use `working-directory` to specify.

```
    - name: Build
      working-directory: TestProj
      run: xcodebuild build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

> On GitHub my project setup TestProj -> TestProj -> TestProj.xcodeproj

From this comment, I'm not sure if the path you need should be `TestProj` or `TestProj/TestProj`.

Comment: let me give it a try and get back to u

Comment: Just tested and I get : Run xcodebuild build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
  xcodebuild build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
##[error]No such file or directory